# Creating a list and set

Tags: python

I have to use IDLE

I need to design a program that does the following:

- Asks the user to enter a series of 10 numbers.
  The program should store the numbers in a list. Give the list created a descriptive name
- Display the following:

  - The lowest number in the list
  - The highest number in the list
  - The total of the numbers in the list
  - The average of the numbers in the list
- Convert the list into a set
- Display the set content. Note that if list contained duplicated numbers, duplicates will no longer appear in the set created.

I'm not very good at Python and it's extremely frustrating for me. Here is what I have:

```
num = int(input('Enter Number:'))

#combine the scores into a single list

number_list = []

print(min(list))
print(max(list))
print(sum(list))
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended as a free do-it-for-you homework completion device. Instead, illustrate a good faith effort on your behalf by sharing an attempt at solving the problem, along with a short explanation as to why the attempt doesn’t meet your requirements. (Please also consider the academic integrity implications of posting coursework for completion by the community on your behalf without at the very least making an attempt at completion.) See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I feel an attempt has been done by OP. That being said, what exactly is the problem you are facing. I see you have done the first 3 points. What is frustrating you?

Comment: @esqew I wasn't looking for someone to complete it for me.  But I do appreciate what you pointed out and how it was stated. I will say that the post could have been made after I had gotten some rest and better well written including my frustration at where I had been failing.in writing the above code.  I also greatly appreciate your See also.  Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
import statistics

# set length of list
length = 10

# create list of numbers
numbers = [int(input("Enter number: ")) for _ in range(length)]

# display the numbers
print("Lowest number: ", min(numbers))
print("Highest number: ", max(numbers))
print("Total of 'numbers': ", sum(numbers))
print("Average of 'numbers'", statistics.mean(numbers))

# convert to set
set_numbers = set(numbers)
print("Set of 'numbers': ", set_numbers)
```

As you can see,

1. I set the length of list
2. Generate a list of 10 numbers where user have to enter them one by one. There are other ways of doing this. For example, by getting numbers in one line and then splitting them based on *space in between*.
3. Now I display all the values you mentioned. To get average you could simply import `statistics` and use `mean()` function. (But if you have any instructions by your teacher not to use any imports then try to implement following solution on your own: divide total of list by amount of numbers)
4. Converting to set is also easy: use `set()` function.

Comment: PS: make sure to look at comment of @esqew . This is not a homework completion service. Make sure to improve next time. And python is the easiest language of them all. I don't understand why you find it so difficult.

Comment: thank you for your example and showing me some of my errors as well as your explanation.  Also I did read and respond to his comments.  I keep hearing python is the easiest, but my brain is very wired for UNIX/LINUX after years in the Navy.

Comment: :) glad i could help